# How do I use new HttpSessionStateWrapper & HttpSessionStateBase?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I read a comment from an answer to [Session variables in ASP.NET MVC](http:///a/560115/4850040). It is recommending to use `HttpSessionStateWrapper` and `HttpSessionStateBase` as opposed to using session directly as follows: `Session["MyValue"]`:

> If ASP MVC is being used then it is preferable to not use the actual
>   Session object from HttpContext.Current.Session but to use the new
>   HttpSessionStateWrapper & HttpSessionStateBase from
>   System.Web.Abstractions.dll then use a Factory or DI to get the
>   Session.

Can someone provide an MVC example of using these two aforementioned classes to initialize, retrieve, and set session variables ?

Comment: I happened to see this comment and reference to what the OP attempted to ask here - it is from a highly marked up comment on: HttpSessionStahttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/560084/session-variables-in-asp-net-mvc/560115#560115eWrapper

Comment: Check out [Darin's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5448138/1123275) for a good example of how to use the 2 classes and explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11643721/how-to-persist-data-using-session-variable-in-mvc3-razor-view/11643842#11643842) might be what you are looking for.

Might also make sense to ask whoever wrote this what he means by that.